# vivaldi browser url tracking in .net

Tags: c#, cross-platform, desktop-application, avalonia, vivaldi

I'am developing Avalonia crossplatform desktop application, in which I want to get the current active tab url of the vivaldi browser.I get the code to track the url in Linux and Mac os, but can't track the in windows os.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          So anybody please help me to get the c# code for that.